# Mongoid Rails - Compare 2 arrays to see if any of the elements matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, mongoid

Basically I need to compare 2 arrays in order to know if the user speaks the language chosen in the filter:

```
User 1 = ['english','portuguese']
User 2 = ['chinese','portuguese']
User 3 = ['portuguese','german']

Filter1 = ['portuguese']
Filter2 = ['portuguese','english']
Filter3 = ['english', 'chinese']
```

Filter 1 should match all 3.
Filter 2 should match all 3.
Filter 3 should match 1 and 2.

This is the query i have right now:

```
@sss = @listings.where("account.profile.spoken_languages" => {"$in" => @languages_array})
```

But somehow this doesnt work.

Any help?

Comment: The query looks all right and [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) do confirm it, so I suspect that either `@languages_array` (please drop the `_array`, no one does name variable like that in ruby) is empty or you got that `account.profile.spoken_languages` wrong. Not eough code to say for sure.

Comment: may be try to rewrite like this: @listings.where(:"account.profile.spoken_languages".in => @languages_array)